# What does “draft” mean in “draft a cyclist”?

Tags: meaning

I would like to be able to understand [this question](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/5955/is-it-considered-rude-to-draft-other-random-cyclists).

Also, in British English, would this be named "draughting"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The definition of [draft](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/draft) in this scenario is

> To move, ride, or drive close behind a fast-moving object so as to
>   take advantage of the slipstream, especially in a race

There's a whole [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drafting_%28aerodynamics%29) on this

> In British English, would this be named draughting?

I have come across [this biking forum](http://www.bikeradar.com/beginners/forums/viewtopic.php?p=15451417&sid=484c5eeafb54859110a0a6d70b0c51c6) referring to this as draughting/drafting. But may be an expert in BrE would like to confirm whether this is standard spelling.

Answer (score 2):

Drafting is when you follow closely behind another moving object (usually vehicles on a highway is what this word is used for in this scenario) that the effects of friction from the air slowing you down is minimized.

18 wheelers make use of this to save gas, by drafting behind each other, and switching periodically.

Physics of it involves wind resistance and drag I believe.

Answer (score 1):

I might add to the fine answers already posted that a cyclist enjoys significant reduction in expended energy when drafting behind another.

This [Guardian.co.uk](http://www.guardian.co.uk/environment/bike-blog/2011/aug/25/cycling-commuter-drafting-etiquette) article has a nice pic of drafting. If you would accept the Guardian as a standard of BrE, then it looks like *drafting* is the spelling to use.

Also, a cursory search of our [sister site](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com) (from which the OP formed the question) shows no hits for *draughting* but 6 for *drafting*. Some of the *bicycles* OPs indicate they are from the UK.

Answer (score 1):

> In British English, would this be named draughting?

*Drafting* is common in British English, although [*draughting*](http://www.guardian.co.uk/discussion/comment-permalink/12138457) has been suggested:

> Given that this is Britain and not the USA, could we call this
>   practice "draughting" and not "drafting"? In UK English a draught is a
>   current of air, a prolonged ingurgitation of drink, a technical
>   drawing or a ship's depth in the water; a draft is a money transfer,
>   an edition of a manuscript or a call-up for military service.